# Rails 3 Saving with Multiple Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I am building a Rails 3 app with a job board, where workers can submit bids for jobs. I have the following associations:

```
Job:
  has_many :bids
  has_many :workers, :through => :bid

Bid:
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :worker

Worker:
  has_many :bids
  has_many :jobs, :through => :bid
```

I have a form on the Show Job Page in which workers can submit bids. In the controllers, I have the following:

```
Job Controller:
  def show
    @bid = current_worker.bids.build
  end   

Bid Controller:
  def create
    @bid = current_worker.bids.build(params[:bid])
    @bid.save
  end
```

With the code above, a submitted bid will not save correctly because it is missing the job_id:

1) What is the correct way to save the bid with BOTH the job_id and worker_id?

2) (I am having trouble passing the job_id from the Job Controller show method to the Bid Controller create method) - is it secure to pass the job_id in a sessions variable?

For reference, the bid form looks like:

```
<%= form_for(@bid) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :min_price, "Minimum Price" %>
  <%= f.text_field :min_price %>

  <%= f.label :fee %>
  <%= f.text_field :fee %>

  <%= f.label :comments %>
  <%= f.text_area :comments, placeholder: "Comments..." %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `bids_controller#create` method be calling `new` instead of `build`? Why not simply add `<%= f.hidden_field :job_id, @job.id %>` in your `form_for(@bid)`?

Comment: Passing the job_id as a hidden field is not safe/secure. The user could use firebug or another program to change the job_id when submitting the form.

Comment: And if they can bid for any job then it doesn't matter. If there are restrictions on the job id you should probably be validating it server side anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code depends on what safety you want, I suppose you want to have to protected jobs which `current_worker` can't make bids to, so you need that does not seems to depend on bid, instead in job.

As you are first creating a bid you can pass job_id, in the form or as part of the route.

If you want to deny a worker to bid to any job you could do something like this:

```
Bids Controller:

  def create
    job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    if current_worker.can_bid? job
      @bid = current_worker.bids.build params[:bid]
    else
      # handle unauthorised bidding
```

In worker model, this is just an example:

```
def can_bid?(job)
  # Implement code here
  # example:
  # job.public? or invited_to?(job)
end

# example of invited_to?(job)
def invited_to?(job)
  job.invitees.include? self
end
```

I am not sure if this answers your question.

I think you could use this to pass job id in route:

## Routes

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :bids
end
```

## View

```
= form_for @job, @bid ...
```

As in first time you don't have @job, you can use:

```
= form_for :job, @bid
```

Comment: Juanpastas - how do I pass the job_id as part of the route rather than in the form?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a rails newbie but I think instead of saying

```
<%= form_for(@bid) do |f| %>
```

try

```
<%= form_for(@job, @bid) do |f| %>
```

then in your bid controller new action do something like this

```
def new
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @bid = @job.bids.build
end
```

and then in your routes you should nest the bid under the job resources like

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :bids
end
```

that should do it I hope, like I said I'm a newbie and may be wrong on this.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your model Bid. Its belogs to two models. So You have to make it as polymorphic table. Re Structure your models as follows

```
Bid:
  belongs_to :bidable, polymorphic: true

Job:
  has_many :workers, :through => :bid
  has_many :bids, :as => :bidable

Worker:
  has_many :bids, :as => :bidable
  has_many :jobs, :through => :bid
```

Comment: I see - I read up on the polymorphic table and it makes sense. But once I make the changes your suggest, how do I modify the job controller and bid controller (and the form if necessary), to create a new bid while saving both the job_id and worker_id without using a hidden form to store the id's?